# how to know User have entered wrong password or pattern? (android lock)

Tags: android, service, administration, lockscreen

I want a service to look if user enters wrong pattern and number of that.
I Googled it, but got nothing useful. some say it's impossible, because it's for Android system and inaccessible, and there are some saying it's possible and they're talking about "PASSWORD_FAILED attempts" or something.
And I think it's completely possible, because there is an app when you enter a wrong pattern, it takes a picture with front camera.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can anyone tell the steps I should go through? I'm trying to write the same app I mentioned in my question, the one takes picture in every failed password attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device administrator can use the `<watch-login />` policy to see this. It receives `ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED` or `ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED` each time, and it can use `DevicePolicyManager#getCurrentFailedPasswordAttempts` to query for it.

See [Device Administration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I forgot to mention that I'm new in android. so may I ask you to explain a little bit more?! ;) or maybe a sample source or tutorial page for that? thanks a lot.